# Magento 2 TEST_SUITE=functional ACCEPTANCE_INDEX=1

Tags: unit-tests, magento2.2-dev, travis

Pull request errored with message:

"The job exceeded the maximum time limit for jobs, and has been terminated."
ref: https://travis-ci.org/magento/magento2/jobs/285215690

Never used before.! what to do? help.

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

That's a problem with Travis, not on your side. The Travis job can be re-run, then it should work. In your case, I see it alrady has been taken care of. Thanks for your contribution!